# FTB Unstable Crash on Startup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm running windows 8.1 and when i try to launch FTB Unstable 1.7.2 (v1.0.4) it would get frozen for a few seconds and then it would print in the log a crash report that only says: **null: java.lang.NullPointerException** in red text. Thanks in advance.

Full log:

```
[19:13:15] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:29: FTBLaunch starting
 up (version 1.3.14 Build: 10314)
[19:13:15] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:30: Java version: 1.7.0_55
[19:13:15] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:31: Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
[19:13:15] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:32: Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
[19:13:15] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:33: Java specification: Java Virtual
 Machine Specification version: 1.7 by Oracle Corporation
[19:13:15] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:35: Java vm: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM version: 24.55-b03 by Oracle Corporation
[19:13:15] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:36: OS: Windows 8.1 6.3 (64-bit)
[19:13:15] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:37: Launcher Install Dir: E:\Windows 8
[19:13:15] [INFO] JGoogleAnalyticsTracker$2.run:484: AnalyticsBackgroundThread started
[19:13:16] [INFO] LaunchFrameHelpers.printInfo:38: System memory: 4128M free, 5119M total
[19:13:16] [ERROR] OutputOverride.write:46: From Console: Jul 08, 2014 7:13:16 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences  WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[19:13:19] [INFO] JavaFinder.parseJavaVersion:157: The FTB Launcher has found the following Java versions installed:
[19:13:19] [INFO] JavaFinder.parseJavaVersion:159: Java Version: 1.7.0_55 sorted as: 1.7.0_55 64 Bit Java at : C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
[19:13:19] [INFO] avaFinder.parseJavaVersion:159: Java Version: 1.8.0_20-ea sorted as: 1.8.0_20 32 Bit Java at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe
[19:13:19] [INFO] JavaFinder.parseJavaVersion:159: Java Version: 1.7.0_55 sorted as:
 1.7.0_55 64 Bit Java at : C:\Windows\system32\java.exe
[19:13:19] [INFO] JavaFinder.parseJavaVersion:159: Java Version: 1.7.0_55 sorted as: 1.7.0_55 64 Bit Java at : C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
[19:13:19] [INFO] JavaFinder.parseJavaVersion:185: Preferred: Java Version: 1.7.0_55 sorted as: 1.7.0_55 64 Bit Java at : C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
[19:13:19] [INFO] DownloadUtils.run:349: DownloadUtils.run() starting
[19:13:19] [INFO] DownloadUtils.run:370: Balance Settings: 0.6 > 0.3805838999132759
[19:13:19] [INFO] DownloadUtils.run:373: Balance has selected Automatic:CurseCDN
[19:13:20] [INFO] DownloadUtils.run:429: DL ready
[19:13:20] [INFO] DownloadUtils.run:461: Using download server Automatic:CurseCDN on host ftb.cursecdn.com (198.41.209.103)
[19:13:21] [INFO] I18N.addFiles:130: [i18n] Fallback enUS loaded
[19:13:21] [INFO] I18N.setLocale:153: [i18n] enUS English language file loaded!
[19:13:21] [INFO] LocaleUpdater.run:76: [i18n] Checking for updates ...
[19:13:22] [INFO] LocaleUpdater.run:93: [i18n] remoteVer = 10
[19:13:22] [INFO] LocaleUpdater.run:106: [i18n] localVer = 10
[19:13:22] [INFO] LocaleUpdater.run:111: [i18n] Files are up to date
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 0 enUS to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 1 cyGB to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 2 daDK to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 3 deDE to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 4 esES to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 5 frFR to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 6 itIT to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 7 maHU to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 8 nlNL to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 9 ptBR to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 10 ptPT to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 11 ruRU to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] OptionsPane.:155: [i18n] Added 12 svSE to options pane
[19:13:23] [INFO] I18N.setLocale:153: [i18n] enUS English language file loaded!
[19:13:23] [INFO] AuthlibDLWorker.doInBackground:58: debug: AuthlibDLWorker: Loading Authlib...
[19:13:24] [INFO] ModpackLoader.run:60: Loading modpack information for modpacks.xml...
[19:13:24] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 1 (Monster)
[19:13:25] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 2 (Pax East 2014 Map)
[19:13:25] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 3 (Direwolf20)
[19:13:25] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 4 (Horizons)
[19:13:25] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 5 (Tech World 2)
[19:13:25] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 6 (Magic World 2)
[19:13:25] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 7 (FTBLite2)
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 8 (FTB Unleashed)
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpackLoader.run:60: Loading modpack information for EPiCCRAFT.xml...
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 9 (FTB Ultimate)
[19:13:26] [INFO] TexturePackLoader.run:42: loading texture pack information...
19:13:26] [INFO] MapLoader.run:42: loading map information...
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 10 (Unstable 1.7.2)
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 11 (FTB Lite)
[19:13:26] [INFO] AuthlibDLWorker.downloadJars:134: Local Authlib Version is good, skipping Download
[19:13:26] [INFO] AuthlibDLWorker.doInBackground:69: Adding Authlib to Classpath
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 12 (Magic Farm 2:Adventures in Technology)
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 13 (BloodNBones)
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 14 (Agrarian Skies: Hardcore Quest)
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 15 (Voxel)
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 16 (Infamy)
[19:13:26] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 17 (Lapito's Galacticraft Modpack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 18 (Direwolf20 1.5 v2)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 19 (Direwolf20 Pack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 20 (MindCrack Pack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 21 (YogCraft Modpack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 22 (FTB Unhinged)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 23 (New World Mod Pack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 24 (RPG Immersion Pack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 25 (BronyModPack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 26 (Ampz Modpack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 27 (VoxelModPack)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 28 (Magic Farm)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 29 (Magic World)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 30 (Tech World)
[19:13:27] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 31 (Pax Challenge Pack)
[19:13:28] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 32 (Feed The Beast Retro SSP)
[19:13:28] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 33 (Feed The Beast Retro SMP)
[19:13:28] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 34 (Slow's Stream Pack)
[19:13:28] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 35 (Feed The Beast Beta Pack A)
[19:13:28] [INFO] ModpacksPane$8.run:315: Adding pack 36 (EPiCCRAFT)
[19:13:28] [INFO] TexturepackPane$4.run:229: Adding texture pack 1 (Soartex Fanver)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 1 (Agrarian Skies Default Map)
[19:13:28] [INFO] TexturepackPane$4.run:229: Adding texture pack 2 (Jadedcat Mixpack)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 2 (Agrarian Skies Flat Map)
[19:13:28] [INFO] TexturepackPane$4.run:229: Adding texture pack 3 (Faithful)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 3 (Agrarian Skies Server Map)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 4 (Direwolf20 Map Ep.0)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 5 (FTB Pax Challenge)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 6 (Direwolf20 Map Ep.0)
[19:13:28] [INFO] TexturepackPane$4.run:229: Adding texture pack 4(JohnSmith Technicians Remix)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 7 (Direwolf20 Map Ep.10)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 8 (Direwolf20 Map Ep.20)
[19:13:28] [INFO] TexturepackPane$4.run:229: Adding texture pack 5 (Familiar yet Different)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 9 (Direwolf20 Map Ep.30)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 10 (Direwolf20 Map Ep.40)
[19:13:28] [INFO] TexturepackPane$4.run:229: Adding texture pack 6 (Love And Tolerance)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 11 (Direwolf20 Map Ep.50)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 12 (Direwolf20 Map Ep.80)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 13 (FTB Normal)
[19:13:28] [INFO] MapsPane$4.run:230: Adding map 14 (FTB Insanity)
[19:13:33] [INFO] LaunchFrame.doLogin:689: Logging in...
[19:13:33] [INFO] LaunchFrame$15.done:732: Login complete.
[19:13:33] [INFO] LaunchFrame.runGameUpdater:781: DEBUG: runGameUpdater: ForceUpdate: false
[19:13:33] [INFO] LaunchFrame.runGameUpdater:782: DEBUG: runGameUpdater: installPath: E:\Windows 8
[19:13:33] [INFO] LaunchFrame.runGameUpdater:783: DEBUG: runGameUpdater: pack dir:
 ftb_17testpack
[19:13:33] [INFO] LaunchFrame.runGameUpdater:784: DEBUG: runGameUpdater: pack check path: ftb_17testpack\version
[19:13:43] [INFO] MinecraftLauncherNew.syncAssets:238: Syncing Assets:
[19:13:54] [INFO] MinecraftLauncherNew.launchMinecraft:74: Java Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
[19:13:54] [INFO] MinecraftLauncherNew.launchMinecraft:75: Pack: Unstable 1.7.2 1.7.2
[19:13:54] [INFO] MinecraftLauncherNew.setMemory:221: Setting MinMemory to 256
[19:13:54] [INFO] MinecraftLauncherNew.setMemory:223: Setting MaxMemory to 2048
[19:13:54] [INFO] MinecraftLauncherNew.launchMinecraft:97: Defaulting PermSize to 256m
[19:13:54] [ERROR] ProcessBuilder.start:-1->LaunchFrame.launchMinecraftNew:1135: null:
 java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown
 Source)
 net.ftb.mclauncher.MinecraftLauncherNew.launchMinecraft(MinecraftLauncherNew.java:212)
 net.ftb.gui.LaunchFrame.launchMinecraftNew(LaunchFrame.java:1095)
 net.ftb.gui.LaunchFrame.setupNewStyle(LaunchFrame.java:877)
 net.ftb.gui.LaunchFrame.runGameUpdater(LaunchFrame.java:826)
 net.ftb.gui.LaunchFrame.access$600(LaunchFrame.java:120)
 net.ftb.gui.LaunchFrame$15.done(LaunchFrame.java:738)
 javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(Unknown Source)
 javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown
 Source) sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
 javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(Unknown
 Source) javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
 Source) java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you updated your java?

Comment: Yes several times. I have read somewhere that the problem has fixed after installing java 7u55 but it still did not fix even with the most up to date version.

Comment: Just so you know other modpacks work but this one wont launch.

Comment: Which modpack are you using? I noticed you didn't mention it anywhere. Or are you referring to the launcher?

Comment: It says in the title. Im using FTB Unstable 1.7.2 (v1.0.4)

Comment: Oh WOW I'm an idiot, sorry about that. I know this may sound redundant, but did you download the x64 or x32 version? And when you reinstalled, did you completely uninstall, reboot, and then reinstall on a completely clean slate?

Comment: Its okay. I have Uninstalled it and installed the x64 version because i can use it. And yes i did it all on a clean slate. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15618/discussion-between-mike6715b-and-slow-excellence).

Comment: It's probably called "Unstable" for a reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [requesting **technical support for a modded Minecraft crash issue**](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797). We allow an exception for unmodded or 'Vanilla' Minecraft, please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash Question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9943/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was i was running Java 8! And Java 8 breaks MinecraftForge so i needed to go to a site (Link below!) and follow the instructions and it is working again! I suggest all having this problem do the same!

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2206446-forge-1-6-4-1-7-2-java-8-compatibility-patch

Better explanation:
   The thing that was cosing the problem was CoreModManager in Minecraft  Forge and all you need to do is download either the 1.7.2 version or the 1.6.4 version and place it in the appropriate directory.

Links to Both CoreModManager:
   [CoreModManager.class, for Forge #965 for Minecraft 1.6.4.](http://www.fybertech.net/minecraft/forgefix/CoreModManager.class)

[CoreModManager.class, for Forge #1121 / #1147 for Minecraft 1.7.2](http://www.fybertech.net/minecraft/forgefix/172/CoreModManager.class)

[CoreModManager.class](http://www.fybertech.net/minecraft/forgefix/1710/CoreModManager.class), for Forge #1208 for Minecraft 1.7.10]

Instructions:
   -- Vanilla --

I'm going to assume you already have Forge installed into the vanilla launcher for these instructions.

From here you need to find your way into your libraries directory for Forge. On Windows, the direct route would be:

For 1.6.4: %appdata%.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\minecraftforge\9.11.1.965

For 1.7.2: %appdata%.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.7.2-10.12.2.1147 (or switch 1147 for the version you're using)

If you use Linux then you know your way around your home directory. And if you use OSX, then I'm sure someone else can help you find it, but I imagine that your base Minecraft directory is in your home directory somewhere as well like Linux.

You can make a backup of the JAR if you want at this point. But now open up the JAR in WinRAR or what ever program you use for such things. First, go ahead and delete the META-INF directory in the root of the JAR, or you'll get a crash related to security, just like in the old JAR-modding days. Now navigate your way through cpw/mods/fml/relauncher. You should see a CoreModManager.class in here. Just drop this patched version on top, and you should be good to go!

-- FTB --

This is relatively identical to the above instructions. The only difference is that you have to find the libraries directory inside your FTB directory instead. Then do the same process as above, and this should fix every related pack on the launcher.

-- Technic --

This is a bit different. You need to patch individual modpacks. And every time a pack is updated, you'll probably have to patch it again. But it's not a big deal. For this, first go into your packs directory. For Windows this is: %appdata%.technic\modpacks

Now go into whichever pack you want to fix. For this example we'll use the main Tekkit. So navigate into tekkitmain, then into bin. You should see a modpack.jar here. This is basically your Forge JAR. Follow the process of above for patching the JAR, of deleting META-INF and adding the class file into the appropriate place, and your pack should now run again.

-- ATLauncher --

Again, this is slightly different, requiring you to fix per-instance like Technic. Go to your ATLauncher directory, then into instances. Find the instance you want to repair, then go into jarmods. You should see the Forge JAR here. So do the above mentioned process to patch the JAR, and the pack should be fixed. Like Technic, updates might break it.

-- MultiMC --

I have no easy fix for this at this time, because it automatically redownloads the Forge JAR after it detects modification, which is both nice and annoying depending on the situation!

-- Servers --

In this case, Forge will already be in the server JAR. You won't want to erase all of META-INF or the server won't launch, just deleting FORGE.DSA is enough according to DAOWAce's post below. Then just copy the class file you downloaded into the appropriate place in the JAR.

-- Misc --

Now for the technical details of what this does, for those interested. Java 8 update 20 changed the way Collections.sort works, no longer cloning a List but modifying it in-place. Since FML is iterating this list at this particular moment, you get the crash. So what this patch does is replace Collections.sort with a wrapper function inside CoreModManager.

It does this:

public static  void sort(List list, Comparator c)
{
T[] toSort = list.toArray((T[])new Object[list.size()]);
Arrays.sort(toSort, c);
for (int j = 0; j < toSort.length; j++) list.set(j, toSort[j]);
}

This is basically a modified version of the same code used to fix later versions of FML, just implemented differently for the sake of a patch.

What I did was compile this bit of code in an otherwise empty class, then used Java Bytecode Editor to extract the bytecode from that class and create the identical method in CoreModManager. Lastly I modified the sortTweakList method to invoke cpw/mods/fml/relauncher/CoreModManager/sort instead of java/util/Collections/sort. You can use JBE to confirm youself that that's the only difference between this patched file and the original if you're concerned at all.

There's a chance that the 1.6.4 patch will work on other versions of Forge for 1.6.x, you would just have to try it and see. The two 1.7.2 builds are the 'latest' and 'recommended' ones, and both had an identical version of CoreModManager, though it might work on earlier builds for that version as well if necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please summarize the instructions at the link.  That way, if the page ever goes down, your answer is still good.  Besides it saves people a click.

Comment: If there is any more problems feel free to comment on this post and i'l try to get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using java x64? if so theres a 8th version of java, maybe it works with it.

```
[19:13:54] [INFO] MinecraftLauncherNew.launchMinecraft:74: Java Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

here is to see you are still using version 7 of Java, update your Java and your Java Path in the server.bat, like (my case)

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe" -Xmx1G -jar Hexxit.jar nogui
```

Comment: Testing your sollution right now!

Comment: Not working getting the same problem...
Error while running launchMinecraft(): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: may you give me the whole error log?

Comment: That is the FULL extended Log.